# ASP.NET Core Application using Entity Framework does not login to SQL database using integrated security

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a simple ASP.NET Core MVC project targeting .NET 5.0 which takes data from a form and supposed to save it to a  table on SQL Server.  I am using entity framework core code-first on an existing database.  I have configured the application according to this post by [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).  This is the connection string.

```
data source=mynetworksqlserver;initial catalog=mycatalog;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

When I go to save changes I get an error:

> SqlException: Login failed for user '' "

On the server that hosts the SQL there is an SQL Server event

> "Login failed for user "".  reason An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed.  Server is configured for Windows authentication only."

I don't understand why the application is not using integrated security:
launch settings:

```
   {"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57731",
      "sslPort": 44382}
    },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"}
     },
    "RC2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" }}}}
```

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
          services.AddDbContext<RevLogonModel>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RevLogon")));
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
      .....
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

Here is an excerpt from the stack trace with to me confirms that its trying to logon with a username and password and not with windows security:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(bool enlistOK)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, bool withFailover)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)

I never had this problem with ASP.NET MVC using .NET framework.  Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because `IIS` is not added to authorized SQL Server users? IOW, check under which user your application is started `Environment.UserName`.

Comment: Thanks for the ide Svyatosslav.  The username is indeed my logon when I'm running it through VS.   When I deploy it to an IIS server I get the name of the pool.  So the application recognizes the windows user but EF is trying to logon using a blank username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem which was in code that I did not present above.  The problem was in my context class.  I used some boilermaker code that contained the wrong connection string.  The code in the context class overrode the code in the startup class so the controller was ignoring the connection string in the startup configuration and using the incorrect one in the context class.  Here is the original code that caused the problem:

```
   public partial class mycontext: DbContext
    {
        public mycontext(DbContextOptions<mycontext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<reviewer> reviewers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RevcommentFile> RevcommentFiles { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder
                  .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=mynetworksqlserver; Initial Catalog=mycatalog;");
            }
        }
     }
```

Replacing the connection string in the context class with the correct connection string (see question) solved the problem.